# POM only project builds going away In jenkins

Tags: maven, build, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a pom only project that is built by Jenkins.  The only thing it really does is send it to my repo.  This is used by several other projects.  For some reason, Jenkins is not keeping these builds. It even seems to be deleting the workspace.  The subversion polling log shows: "No existing build. Scheduling a new one."  This triggers a new build, which triggers a new build for all downstream projects.  Could this be because there are no files generated during the build?  I do NOT have "Delete old builds" checked in the project config.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In Jenkins, Subversion polling can take place from the Master node or from the Slave nodes. By default, in order to reduce load on the master (because Polling is more resource intensive than push notification from a PostCommit hook on the Subversion server - i.e. the recommended way) the default is polling from the slave.

If you use a VM slave pool, or regularly purge slave workspaces, etc. Then slave based polling will have to do a checkout to complete (I think, but I am not sure, that this is because of the potential for `svn:external` entries to be unpinned and therefore trigger an update... but that sounds silly)

You can change the default to be the master by setting the following system property in Jenkins:

```
hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.pollFromMaster=true
```

You will need to restart Jenkins to pick up the change.

If you want to use the Groovy console, you could apply the change to a running Jenkins instance... I think the following will, with changes to fix my possibly borked syntax, work:

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.scm.*
Jenkins.instance.items.each { job ->
    if (job.scm instanceof SubversionSCM) { 
        job.scm.setPollFromMaster(true);
    }
}
```

Though I should point out that the groovy script will only make the change until the next restart of Jenkins as the field it tweaks is transient.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I don't know how this applies to my problem.  I have a single Jenkins instance.  I have no slaves.

Comment: Then I am at a loss... hopefully others will find it helpful though